# Is the set $A =\{x: x^2 < 3x\}$ bounded, find $\sup A$ and $\inf A$ if they exist?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Is the set $A = \{x: x^2 < 3x\}$ bounded? Find $\sup A$ and $\inf A$ if they exist.

My answer is no, it is unbounded and so it has no $\sup$ and $\inf$. Am I correct?

Comment: Write it as $x^2-3x<0$ and factor.

Comment: why do you think it is unbounded?

Comment: so it has 2 upper bounds 0 and 3 ....correct?@ThomasAndrews

Comment: I have changed my mind @SiongThyeGoh

Comment: How can $0$ be an upper bound when it is smaller than any value.  And no real number set can have a a finite number of upper bounds.  If $a$ is an upper bound then so is any of the infinite numbers larger than $a$.  I get the very strong impression you do not understand the basic definitions.  I strongly advise rereading the chapter text several (at least three more times from start to finish).

Comment: Sorry I have made a mistake @fleablood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
x^2 - 3x = x(x-3) < 0
$$

So there are $3$ options.

$x<0$ then both $x$ and $x-3$ are negative so the inequality is not satisfied.

$0<x<3$ then the $x$ factor is positive but $x-3$ is negative so the inequality is satisfied.

$x>3$ then both factors are positive so the inequality is not satisfied.

$A=(0,3)$. It is bounded, has $\inf=0$ and $\sup=3$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that$$x^2 - 3x < 0$$

$$x(x-3) < 0$$

Hence $$0<x<3$$

Note that $0$ is a lower bound. Try to find out the infimum and supremum.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \ge 3$ then $x^2 = x \cdot x \ge 3x$ and $x \not \in A$ so $3$ is an upper bound.

And if $0 < x < 3$ then $x^2 = x\cdot x < 3x$ so $x \in A$ so $(0,3) \subset A$ and no $a < 3$ is an upper bound of $A$.  So $3 = \sup A$ by definition.

If $x < 0$ then $3x < 0$ and $x^2 > 0$ and $x^2 \ge 3x$ so $x \not \in A$.  So $A$ is bounded below by any negative number.  Forthermore $0^2 = 3*0$ so $0 \not \in A$.  So $A$ is bounded below by $0$.

If $a > 0$ then $\frac a2 <  a$ and $\frac a2 \in A$ so no $a > 0$ is an lower bound so $\inf A = 0$ by definition.

Comment: the second line x^2 not x^3.....right?